# Javascript - better way to write this function

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested-loops

I have a Database with linked data. Like "Brands -> Locations -> Cars -> Colors".
I want to get all associated Data to a passed level.

It works only for the first level and with exactly 3 more levels. I want it to work with the level I pass and then do the work for the count of my levels.
How can I write this "hardcoded" stuff into a reusable for loop?

```js
async getData(level, levelCount /*unused*/) {
  let data = [];
  let associatedData0 = {
    id: this.levels[0].id,
    data: [],
  };
  let associatedData1 = await this.updateAssociatedData(
    associatedLevel0.id
  );;
  for (let i = 0; i < associatedData1.length; i++) {
    let dataset = associatedData1[i];
    let associatedLevel1 = {
      id: dataset.id,
      data: [],
    };
    let associatedData2 = await this.updateAssociatedData(
      associatedLevel1.id
    );
    for (let j = 0; j < associatedData2.length; j++) {
      let dataset = associatedData2[j];
      let associatedLevel2 = {
        id: dataset.id,
        data: [],
      };
      let associatedData3 = await this.updateAssociatedData(
        associatedLevel2.id
      );
      for (let k = 0; k < associatedData3.length; k++) {
        let dataset = associatedData3[k];
        let associatedLevel3 = {
          id: dataset.id,
        };
        associatedData2.data.push(associatedLevel3);
      }
      associatedData1.data.push(associatedLevel2);
    }
    associatedData0.data.push(associatedLevel1);
  }
  data.push(associatedData0);
  return data;
},
```

Example data:

```
const input = [{
  "id": "10284599430100800016",
  "data": [{
    "id": "10284600350100800016",
    "data": [{
      "id": "10339076180100200016",
      "data": [
        {"id": "10370061810100200016"},
        {"id": "10353791290100200016"},
        {"id": "10339076410100200016"}
      ]
    }, {
      "id": "10284600850100800016",
      "data": [
        {"id": "10358749360100800016"},
        {"id": "10284604280100800016"}
      ]
    }]
  }]
}];
```

Comment: You can try a recursive function to work with arbitrarily deeply nested objects

Comment: @mplungjan it looks like this:
[{"id":"10284599430100800016","data":[{"id":"10284600350100800016","data":[{"id":"10339076180100200016","data":[{"id":"10370061810100200016"},{"id":"10353791290100200016"},{"id":"10339076410100200016"}]},{"id":"10284600850100800016","data":[{"id":"10358749360100800016"},{"id":"10284604280100800016"}]}]}]}]
How can I write this as a recursive function?

Comment: @canbax can you help?